# Data binding from XML file [UWP]

Tags: xaml, uwp, binding

I have xml file with some data that I would like to bind it to the textblocks. The code below does not add any content to textblocks. What I am doing wrong. Any advice ?

XAML:

```
<GridView x:Name="DataGrid1">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid  Background="AliceBlue" Width="300" Height="200">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                   </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
```

C#

```
string XMLPath = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "booksData/data.xml");
            XDocument loadedD = XDocument.Load(XMLPath);

            var newData = from query in loadedD.Descendants("element")
                          select new Book
                          {
                              Title = (string)query.Attribute("title"),
                              Category = (string)query.Attribute("category")

                          };
            DataGrid1.ItemsSource = newData;
```

XML:

```
<books>
    <element>
      <category>Thriller</category>
      <description>In The Green Line, </description>
      <id>1</id>
      <image>images/greenLine.jpg</image>
      <price>10.50</price>
      <title>The Green Line</title>
    </element>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The code below does not add any content to textblocks. What I am doing wrong.

The [problem](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_el_vs_attr.asp) is that the *`title`* and *`category`* is `Element` of the book but not `Attribute`. So you need modify your linq like the following

```
var newData = from query in loadedD.Descendants("element")
select new Book
{
  Title = (string)query.Element("title"),
   Category = (string)query.Element("category")    
};
```